# What is the default UIColor of the root window?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uicolor

**iPad only part of my app:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

All my views use the 'default' background colour or:

```
<color key="backgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="groupTableViewBackgroundColor"/> in my storyboard XML.
```

I want to try and ascertain the default colour of the root view (the view at the bottom of the stack), which is:

```
UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
```

The reason for this, is that I am overlaying a view, initially in the detail or right hand side of the UISplitViewController, so that when the detail view loads for the first time, I can put a splash image in this view. When the user selects a table view cell in the left hand navigation controller of the split view controller, details will appear in the right hand side, and the splash view will get removed.

I want to keep the look and feel of my UI consistent. I cannot use the [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor] for the splash view, because this colour is transparent, and will show through the detail view underneath. The detail view at this point consists of a series of labels & text fields. The text fields are empty, because no table view cell on the left hand side navigation controller of the split view controller has been selected yet.

So, I want to try and set the splash view background colour to the same value as the root view or window of my app.

I want the background colour on the right hand side of the first screenshot to match the background colour on the right hand side of the second screenshot (see above). At the moment, the first screenshot has a background colour of white. I cannot seem to match the gray of the second screenshot by eye, so I need to accurately read this value programmatically. Any ideas?

Can you tell me how I can ascertain this value as a UIColor value?

I have tried doing:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
        UINavigationController *detailController = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
        UINavigationBar *navBar = navigationController.navigationBar;
        navBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.968627f green:0.584314f blue:0.12549f alpha:1.0f];
        UINavigationBar *navBarDetail = detailController.navigationBar;
        navBarDetail.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.968627f green:0.584314f blue:0.12549f alpha:1.0f];
        UIToolbar *toolBar = navigationController.toolbar;
        UIToolbar *toolBarDetail = detailController.toolbar;
        NSLog(@"rootviewcontrollerColor: %@",self.window.backgroundColor);
        splitViewController.delegate = (id)detailController.topViewController;
    }
    else{
        UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        UINavigationBar *navBar = navController.navigationBar;
        navBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.968627f green:0.584314f blue:0.12549f alpha:1.0f];
        UIToolbar *toolBar = navController.toolbar;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

The output from the NSLog is:

2016-11-03 14:06:49.610 Yoga Therapy[96158:19a03] rootviewcontrollerColor: (null)

**UPDATE:**

When I try:

NSLog(@"rootviewcontrollerColor: %@",self.window.rootViewController.view.backgroundColor);

I get:

UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 1

How can I convert this into UIColor?

**UPDATE:**

Let me try & explain this another way. Imagine creating an app that  has a single UIView, with the default background colour [groupTableViewBackgroundColor], as the root controller. When you run the code in the simulator, the iPad will be filled with a gray colour. What is the RGB value of this colour? The closest word I can think of, to describe this colour is the 'System window colour'...

Comment: self.window.rootViewController.view.backgroundColor is already a UIColor. Are you expecting that NSLog would print out that it's UIColor.gray or something?

Comment: @David Lari I was hoping I could have an rgb representation, because I do not how to convert UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 1 into rgb for use with UIColor?

Comment: @David Lari Sorry David. Are you saying that UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 1 is a valid UIColor value? Like [UIColor UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 1]?

Comment: I am trying to work out what UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 1 is in RGB, so I can use that colour reference for another UIView...

Comment: Unrelated but is that an iOS 6 screenshot in 2016? *-*

Comment: Yes. And I know what you are going to say next;)...I cannot upload iOS6 apps to the App Store. But, please, can we park that problem for now. I have got that issue covered...

Comment: I'm sorry, I really don't understand what you are trying to do and I expect you are doing it in a fundamentally suboptimal way to begin with. It looks like Md Ibrahim Hassan has given you the RGB values in his answer anyway, though I'm not sure why you would need those when you can just grab the backgroundColor from the view and stick it on the background of the other view.

Comment: @David Lari "Grab the backgroundColor from the view". This is the problem. What view should I use Md Ibrahim Hassan code on? Because when I try it on self.window.rootViewController.view, I get NSLog of colorString = 0 0 0 1. This is 'black', which is impossible. I am looking for a shade of gray [see screenshot].

Comment: @David Lari If you don't understand what I am trying to do, how can you conclude that I am doing 'it' [whatever 'it' is] sub optimally. Your statement is clearly illogical.

Comment: Your newly added screen shot clarifies things somewhat. Have you checked to see if it's tableView.backgroundView.backgroundColor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CGColorRef colorRef = self.window.rootViewController.view.backgroundColor.CGColor;
NSString *colorString = [CIColor colorWithCGColor:colorRef].stringRepresentation;
NSLog(@"colorString = %@", colorString);
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doesn't tell me what the root background colour is? Your code is just a conditional that tells me whether the colour is orange or not?

Comment: Thanks for this. So Can I use UIDeviceWhiteColorSpace 0 1 as the colorRef to get its RGB representation?

Comment: BTW if your objective is to check if the colors are same then my previous answer was what you was the solution. Whats the point in logging in out.

Comment: My objective is to find out the RGB float color values of the rootviewcontroller...

Comment: @CharlesRobertson please check the screenshot I attached to my answer it shows the console output for the exact code implementation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127324/discussion-between-md-ibrahim-hassan-and-charles-robertson).

Comment: I am trying to find out what the darker gray colour is, in my second screenshot. This represents the colour of the very first view in the stack, because all the other views on top of it, are 'groupTableViewBackgroundColor'. 'groupTableViewBackgroundColor' is a transparent colour, so it allows the very first view to show through...

Comment: I think the code I gave is correct now with proper screenshot to support the output. I hope you are satisfied with the answer.

Comment: This line is causing an error: NSString *colorString = [CIColor colorWithCGColor:colorRef].stringRepresentation;

Comment: The bit after the . looks strange. How about NSString *colorString = [CIColor colorWithCGColor:colorRef.stringRepresentation];

Comment: no the format is correct the dot is part of the code

Comment: I hope then it is some other issue I tested it for a View Controller before sharing it with you. Anyways hope you find the solution.

Comment: Apple Mach-O LInked Error   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CIColor", referenced from:...

Comment: Do I need to import a library or header file to support CIColor?

Comment: I added CoreImage framework, and the NSLog gave me: colorString = 0 0 0 1, which is black. And, clearly, the colour I am expecting is a shade of gray, so I cannot accept your answer, but thank you for showing me how to convert CIColor to UIColor...